# Can I make a method in C# accept a variable number of arguments and then process these

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement something like this Java code in C#

```
    public void log(Object... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (args[i] instanceof long[]) {
                args[i] = Arrays.toString((long []) args[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it at all possible in C# ?

Comment: Look at `params object[] args`, you can see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

Comment: use `is` keyword to check the type, `if(args[i] is long[]])`

Comment: `public void log(params Object[] args){for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)if (args[i] is long[]) args[i] = ((long[])args[i]).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) like so from the documentation

```
public static void UseParams(params int[] list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```